# Fatal Error in WordPress WooCommerce theme "Call to undefined function wc_get_theme_slug_for_templates()"

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, fatal-error

I am new in WordPress. I am trying to make e-commerce site. I have used plugin WooCommerce and a Woocommerce theme.

My WooCommerce Theme Menu Bar look like:

[image: theme Menu]

All links of theme menu working except shop and I am getting this error at the end of "Shop" page:

[image: error image]

Error Description:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   wc_get_theme_slug_for_templates() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress2\wp-content\themes\vw-ecommerce-shop\woocommerce\global\wrapper-end.php:23
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress2\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\wc-core-functions.php(195):
>   include() #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress2\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\wc-template-functions.php(400):
>   wc_get_template('global/wrapper-...') #2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress2\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(286):
>   woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end('') #3
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress2\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(310):
>   WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array) #4
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress2\wp-includes\plugin.php(453):
>   WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #5
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress2\wp-content\themes\vw-ecommerce-shop\woocommerce\archive-product.php(110):
>   do_action('woocommerce_aft...') #6
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress2\wp-includes\template-loader.php(74):
>   include('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #7
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress2\wp-blog-header.php(19): in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress2\wp-content\themes\vw-ecommerce-shop\woocommerce\global\wrapper-end.php
>   on line 23

Please help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the error is telling you this:

The error comes from this theme file:

```
\themes\vw-ecommerce-shop\woocommerce\global\wrapper-end.php
```

Line: 23.

In that file on line 23 the following function is called `wc_get_theme_slug_for_templates()` but at that point it's not (yet) available.
The function should be available though, because it's a valid Woocommerce function, see [here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_get_theme_slug_for_templates.html).

Can you update your theme? It's always important to keep the theme up-to-date with WooCommerce, otherwise problems will arrise eventually (and probably sooner than expected).

Regards, Bjorn

Comment: i have updated the theme as you said, but it does'nt work for me.

Comment: I explained the error to you, the theme is causing this. I suggest you contact the theme support, don't forget to mention you're running this on a local xampp setup.

Comment: theme updation was failed! so I added another theme of woocommerce store and now its working.

Comment: You're welcome :-), please set my answer as accepted if it helped you, thanks!